# How to make translucent text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, textstyle

How to create semi-translucent text like in beginning of that website https://superscene.pro/
I really wonder how to make text stay with define color and become translucent when there is object behind it ? Maybe someone can give tips on how to make dragging of object like on that website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using:

```
mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
```

You know, there is something called "inspector" where you can see styles and edit tags about the document. The inspector looks like this:

[image: Inspector example]

Answer (score 0):

From looking at their source in the CSS, it appears to be coming from the following rule:

```css
mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
```

Adding this rule should do what you desire. If you want more information, I recommend looking here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css mix-blend-mode` on text container or in text itself and you can give color to text to give more details, more info [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/)

```css
.bg{
  background-image:url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/400/400.jpg?hmac=oHJBlOQwtaF75oX43dFtPf4At_GRLEx9FQqkkfpLR5U');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.blend{
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
   <div class="blend">
      <p>This ts text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```